# Jenkins: get environment variables in the body of a global function

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shared global function on PublishGitHub.groovy looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def call(body)
{
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: Publishing...\u001B[m"
    body()
    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: End Publish...\u001B[m"      
}
```

And a code on my JenkinsFile:

```
environment {
    VERSION = "v1.3.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
stages {
    stage ('Publish WebAPI'){
        steps{
            echo "\u001B[32mINFO: Start Publish...\u001B[m"

            PublishGitHub{
                echo "This is a body with version: ${env.VERSION}"
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
INFO: Start Publish...
[Pipeline] echo
INFO: Publishing...
[Pipeline] }
```

And follow next error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'VERSION' on null
>   object

Because inside the body I do not have access to the environment variables?

Comment: I'm confused...where is the "env" defined? I see "environment" but not "env"?

Comment: In Jenkins the environment variables can be accessed using.

Env.

or directly the name, in this case does not modify the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shared library code runs outside of the workflow CPS context, that is why closure you pass to the vars script does not recognize `env` property. You can fix this problem by passing a reference to the workflow script. If you call your function like this

```
PublishGitHub(this) {
    echo "This is a body with version: ${env.VERSION}"
}
```

and you apply a small modification to `vars/PublishGitHub.groovy` script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(config, body) {
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: Publishing...\u001B[m"
    body()
    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: End Publish...\u001B[m"
}
```

then you will run your pipeline successfully:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish WebAPI)
[Pipeline] echo
[32mINFO: Start Publish...[m
[Pipeline] echo
[32mINFO: Publishing...[m
[Pipeline] echo
This is a body with version: v1.3.537
[Pipeline] echo
[32mINFO: End Publish...[m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If you want to limit the scope for the shared library, you can always simply pass `env` instead of `this` and change `vars/PublishGitHub.groovy` to something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(env, body) {
    def config = [
            env: env
    ]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: Publishing...\u001B[m"
    body()
    echo "\u001B[32mINFO: End Publish...\u001B[m"
}
```

In this scenario you give your shared library an access to environment variables only.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the environment variables that you have defined in your Jenkinsfile available in your shared library code you have to pass a **this** parameter on the call to your shared library method.

For example  (below is a partial extract only of a full pipeline file):

```
// JENKINS-42730
@Library('pipeline-shared-library')_
import org.blah.MySharedLibraryClass
// END JENKINS_42730

pipeline {
     agent { any }

     environment {
         FOO = (new MySharedLibraryClass(config, this)).myMethod("StringVar1", "StringVar2")

     }
}
```

My Shared Library:

```
package org.blah

import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

public class MySharedLibraryClass implements Serializable {
    def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
    def config
    def steps

    def ArtifactoryHelper(config, steps) {
        this.config = config
        this.steps = steps
    }

    def log(msg){
        //Allows me to print to Jenkins console
        steps.println(msg)
    }

    def myMethod(var1, var2) {
        ....
    }
```

The this parameter I referred to above maps to steps in the shared library code. You should then be able to resolve `"VERSION=${steps.env.VERSION}"` in your shared library code.

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234721/359540).

Notes:

1. `pipeline-shared-library` is the ID I gave the library in Manage Jenkins > Configure System

Answer (score 1):

Szymon's answer works. I added "p.env = env"

```
def toParam(final Closure body) {
  final def p = [:]
  p.env = env
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = p
  body()
  return p
}
```