# Jenkins custom DSL Cannot invoke method image() on null object

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to define custom DSL refer https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps
it seems work if just define simple command in {}
but failed when use complicated command

```
(root)
+- vars
|      +- shareL.groovy
|      +- xxx.groovy
|      +- monitorStep.groovy
```

shareL.groovy

```
def install(){
   print "test install"
}

def checkout(){
   print "test checkout"

}
```

monitorStep.groovy

```
def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    // This is where the magic happens - put your pipeline snippets in here, get variables from config.
    script {
        def status
        def failed_cause=''
        try{
            body()
        } catch(e){
            status = 'fail'
            failed_cause = "${e}"
            throw e
        }finally {
            def myDataMap = [:]
            myDataMap['stage'] = STAGE_NAME
            myDataMap['status'] = status
            myDataMap['failed_cause'] = failed_cause
            influxDbPublisher selectedTarget: 'myTest', measurementName: 'myTestTable',customData: myDataMap
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkinsfile

```
#!groovy
@Library('myShareLibray@') _

pipeline {
   stages{
       stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                script {
                    monitorStep{
                        shareL.checkout()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                script {
                    monitorStep{
                        docker.image("node").inside(){
                            shareL.install()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }

}
```

first stage failed with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method checkout() on null object
```

second stage failed with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method image() on null object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the closure cannot find the name `shareL` which should be accessible in the closure's delegate, which is in our case the map `config`.
You need to redeclare the map to expose the name `shareL` and additionally a second name `install` which must be invokable.
The solution is to rewrite the map like this:

```
def config = [ shareL : [install: { println "Inside the map" }] ]
body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = config
body()
```

Then when you call body() it will find `shareL.install()` but this will not point to the call() method in the shareL.groovy but to the property in the map.

Comment: thanks, @Catalin I also need use other share library method, so I fixed this problem by passing a reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052626