# How to define credentials and environment variables in jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Currently I am having the following code in my Jenkins file

```
     environment {
        GITHUB_USER = credentials('GITHUB_USER')
        GITHUB_TOKEN= credentials('GITHUB_TOKEN')
        DOCKER_USER = credentials('DOCKER_USER')
        ARTIFACTORY_USER = credentials('ARTIFACTORY_USER')
     }
```

Since this code is being used in several place I want this code to be in shared library
Like vars/commonCredentials.groovy

What's the best way to archive this and how can I use this in my Jenkins file?

Comment: do you want only the credential to be part of the shared library or all the build/deployment steps?
If you feel all the build and deployment pipeline are the same, you could move everything to shared library and reference it from Jenkinsfile

Comment: But It's possible to do it another way around. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234633/access-environment-variables-in-jenkins-shared-library-code) is some discussion from the stack overflow

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel I just have some common credentials that I want to move. I don't want to move entire pipeline

Comment: I don't think it's ever possible to have it in a shared library as declarative pipelines are meant to simplify the pipeline flow not to be for reusable purposes. try to use scripted [withCredential](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

Answer (score 0):

Next code works for me - I exported credentials as variables.

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'svcacct_user', usernameVariable: 'SVCACCT_USER_USR', passwordVariable: 'SVCACCT_USER_PSW')]){
    sh '''#!/bin/bash --login
    echo $SVCACCT_USER_USR
    echo $SVCACCT_USER_PSW
    '''
    }
```